# How to make div content not over floating to the right?

Tags: html, css, styles

When I write a content in my page it will go to right forever and it won't break line, what is the problem? I want the content to stick to the same width but it is okay to over flow on y axis. my code:

```
<div id="mainBody" style="width: 900px;
height: 750px;
float: right;
background-color: #E9E9E9;">
<div id="div1" style="height: 750px; overflow-y: auto; border:1px solid red; width: auto;">
<div id="div2" style="height:710px; padding: 20px; width: 900px; border:1px solid red;"> Content </div></div></div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? You set a div with width: 900px; It doesn't appear to "go to the right forever" at least in my tests. It seems to be doing exactly what you told it to - be 900px in width.

Comment: first. why do you use inline styles and not CSS ? second. `same width` what do you mean by that ? which is the div that is causing the problem etc. please be more specific. keep in mind that we don't know your problem :)

Comment: I have just copied it from my css file, anyway, I want the content not to go forever to the right I want it to line break that's all

Answer (score 0):

First, i think that the div1 and div2 is the problem, why dont you just do it with one element ?

So it will be like this :

```
<div id="mainBody" style="width: 900px;height: 750px;float: right; padding: 20px;background-color: #E9E9E9; border:1px solid red; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto">
  Content
</div>
```

So, #mainBody will wrap it at fixed dimension, with 200px padding, 1px red border, and will overflow scroll vertically

Comment: Try to add `word-wrap: break-word`, and what kind of content you put there exactly ? If you put text there, it should be do line break, even when the `word-wrap` not defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the content not float right or even left ,then you need a clear class which clear your float , so that the next time you enter something that will go below everything and not left or right .Here I am providing you the code below , do check out and share if your problem persists.

```
.clear{
         clear:both;
      }
```

The above code will clear both "float right and float left".
If you want to delete just the right float then you may use

```
.clear{
           clear:right;
      }
```

So now after creating the above class just use this in the html section :

Entire Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<stlye type="text/css">
    .clear
    {
        clear:both;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div id="mainBody" style="width: 900px;
height: 750px;
float: right;
background-color: #E9E9E9;">
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="div1" style="height: 750px; overflow-y: auto; border:1px solid red; width: auto;">
<div id="div2" style="height:710px; padding: 20px; width: 900px; border:1px solid red;"> Content </div></div></div>
</body>
</head>
```

Comment: At which div should I add the class?

Comment: Add it after where you want your content to not float right anymore .

Comment: <div class="clear"></div> ->, you just need to add this after    <div id="mainBody" style="width: 900px;
height: 750px;
float: right;
background-color: #E9E9E9;">